# Ubuntu 20.04 Can't Use Camera Without Sudo

Tags: permissions, root, webcam, camera, guvcview

I have a USB Webcam connected to an Ubuntu 20.04 VM. I want to use the camera so to test it, I use Cheese. It shows a black box. So, I install `guvcview` but that also does the same thing. Only after running `guvcview` with root can I see a webcam feed. Why is this happening and can I fix it. I know that I was able to do it before.

Comment: I have the same problem but on my machine, which is an MSI, I try fn+f6 , and see how appears and disappears with lsubs. `sudo guvcview` works but `guvcview` doesn't. `sudo cheese`doesn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VMWare, change your USB setting from 2.1 to 3.1. Your camera may only support USB 3.0

You can also reload the camera driver:

```
sudo rmmod uvcvideo
sudo modprobe uvcvideo
```

Comment: Reloading drivers works also for built-in camera, for installed distro Ubuntu 21.10 with kernel 5.13. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Many device access problems can be resolved through group membership changes.

Specifically, if `ls -l`  shows that the group permissions (the second "`rwx`" triplet) is "`rw`" (e.g."`-rw-rw----`"), then, adding oneself to the group that owns the device will grant `rw` access.

Here's how:

```
device="/dev/whatever"
sudo adduser $USER $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

This allows you membership in the group that can `rw` the device, but there is one more step.

To make all your processes members of the new group, logout and login. Group memberships are set up at `login` time.

To create a single process in the new group (for testing, prior to logout/login):

```
newgrp $(stat -c "%G" $device)
```

or, just type the group name. See `man newgrp`.